# How to remove the email validation after submit using angular2/typescript

Tags: angular

[image: error image]

I have an add popup, after filling all fields and giving submit, the values are getting saved. If I open again and add popup to add new values without page refresh, in the email field without filling anything it is displaying `Email is invalid`. On pageload it is working fine. Please can anyone help to solve this issue. 
I am here by sharing my code please help

**HTML code**

```
   <md-input-container>
   <input mdInput type="text" name="workEmail" [(ngModel)]="userDetails.workEmail" placeholder="WD Email" #email="ngModel" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" required>
   </md-input-container>
   <div style="font-size: 13px;text-align: left; padding: 8px 0px 8px 30px;" [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine" class="error">
                                Email is invalid!
   </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `untouched` and check once.

```
<md-input-container>
<input mdInput type="text" name="workEmail" [(ngModel)]="userDetails.workEmail" placeholder="WD Email" #email="ngModel" pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$" required>
</md-input-container>
<div style="font-size: 13px;text-align: left; padding: 8px 0px 8px 30px;" [hidden]="email.valid || email.pristine || email.untouched" class="error">
Email is invalid!
</div>
```